# how to declare a variable in C without using white space between datatype and variable name?

Tags: c, variables, lexer

for example,

```
int a;
```

Here there is a **space** between 'int' and 'a'
but what can be the separators other than whitespace?

Comment: May I ask what is the rationale for this question?

Comment: Curiosity? seems like  a perfectly good question to me.

Comment: Seriously?  This is a *bad question*.  Code is meant to communicate to other programmers, or yourself in the future.  Avoiding white space can be done (`int/**/a;`), but it makes it harder for everyone reading the code, and takes *more* space than the straightforward way.   Voting to close as "too localized".  If there are any reasons to do this, they're extremely esoteric.

Comment: @wnoise Some of us are interested in the esoteric.

Comment: @khachik: Future IOCCC contestant?

Comment: @Neil: programming language esoterica can indeed be interesting.  "I need to do it this way because my homework says so" is not.  It's the esoteric *circumstances* required for this to be useful that I object to.

Comment: This question could be valid if the code fragment is being transmitted through shell script or makefile variables with insufficient/improper quoting.

Comment: @wnoise Nobody except you has mentioned homework.

Comment: @Neil: the reasons to do this are (a) crazy environments (too localized) or (b) someone mandating you do it this ways (e.g. homework, or dysfunctional company).   Of these, homework from a bad course seems overwhelmingly most likely.

Comment: @wnoise Or "I wonder if there is any way of doing X?" You seem to have zero intellectual curiosity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a paren:

```
int main() {
    int(a);
    a = 42;
}
```

but please don't.

Comment: @Vlad Well, if I came across it, I'd wonder what the heck was going on, and why the coder chose to  write it that way. So I'd be confused.

Comment: @Neil: thanks neil. it really helped.. but i want to avoid space everywhere in my program.. eg in function declaration also.. can you suggest someother?

Comment: i just tried how to print without semicolon.. similarly trying to know about whitespaces also..

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++, you can use an alternate syntax:

```
int(a)=3;std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
```

Not a single whitespace character.

Comment: Why do you think it is impossible with C? `int(a);printf("a=%d",a);`

Answer (score 2):

> how to declare a variable in C without using white space between datatype and variable name?

```
a;
```

Explanation: on C89, this declares a variable of type `int`. Since there is no datatype, there can be no whitespace between the datatype and the variable name.

Comment: Unfortunately (?) in modern C there is no implicit int.

Comment: @Neil: but if a variable is declared globally without mentioning datatype it is declared as int implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

new line would go. And tab character too.

Answer (score 0):

White-space is the punctuator (a.k.a. 'tokenizer') used when processing declarations (as in variables or functions).

White-space includes space, new lines, and tabs (there's vertical and horizontal, but I only know of horizontal tabs used for writing code).

That said, multiple white-space can be used (as in for display purposes in a text editor), without any effect in the final code.

This means that the following three statements are equivalent:

```
int a;
int          a;
int   
      a;
```

This does not mean that there aren't other tokenizers. The following example is perfectly legal:

`int a;int b;`

For the full list of separators, refer to the [C Language Specification](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1124.pdf)

Comment: Please point out where the C++ standard says so, and if it does, why you can write code like `a+b`?

Comment: Good point. I was referring exclusively to the declaration of the OP. I edited my answer to correct that.

Comment: Actually, the C Standard does not really use the terms "tokeniizers" or  "separators", instead it speaks of "punctuators" - see 6.4.6.

Comment: Actually, the standard talks about preprocessing tokens, which are "matched greedily", i.e. `x+++++y` is parsed as `x ++ ++ + y`.